# An error occurred talking to the iTunes Store with xcode 4.5

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am using Xcode 4.5 (Mac OS X Version 10.7.4) and facing problem to validate and Distribute my application.
Here internet is working fine.And I tried many suggestions posted on net but still could not find any solution.Please help me about what's wrong with me....

Answer (score 0):

In XCode 4.5, you don't use Application Loader anymore. It's all done through XCode's Organizer (Archives tab).

See the Apple documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-archives_organizer/articles/about_archives_organizer.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010547-CH1-SW1

Comment: I'm facing this problem with Archives organizer of Xcode 4.5.

Comment: OK--your initial post said you were using "Application Loader", which is how you submitted apps in the past prior to the XCode Organizer.